# Prove that $F_nF_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}(F_{n+2}^2-F_{n-1}^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci and Lucasnumbers are defined for all integers $n$ by the recurrence relations
$$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\text{ where }F_1=1\text{ and }F_2=1,$$
$$L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}\text{ where }L_1=1\text{ and }L_2=3.$$
I would like to find the cleanest proof that 
$$F_nF_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}(F_{n+2}^2-F_{n-1}^2).$$
Note: I can prove this result using induction, so that is not of interest to me. I can also prove it using Binet's formula, which is obviously doesn't fulfil my want for a "clean" proof. I am aware of formulae such as 
\begin{align*}
F_{n+k}+F_{n-k}=F_nL_k\text{ where $k$ is even,}\\
F_{n+k}+F_{n-k}=L_nF_k\text{ where $k$ is odd,}\\
F_{n+k}-F_{n-k}=F_nL_k\text{ where $k$ is odd,}\\
F_{n+k}-F_{n-k}=L_nF_k\text{ where $k$ is even.}\\
\end{align*}
but these don't seem to be of help as the different between $n+2$ and $n-1$ is $3$ (i.e. the difference is odd). Does anyone have any suggestions for a one line proof (with the use of a suitable identity)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "cleanest" proof is not necessarily a one-line proof.  That said, $$\begin{align*} F_{n+2}^2 - F_{n-1}^2 &= (F_{n+2} + F_{n-1})(F_{n+2} - F_{n-1}) \\ &= ((F_{n+1} + F_n) + (F_{n+1} - F_n))((F_{n+1} + F_n) - (F_{n+1} - F_n)) \\ &= (2F_{n+1})(2F_n) \\ &= 4F_{n+1}F_n, \end{align*}$$ and the result immediately follows.

Comment: You're right. This is the nicest proof. I was kind of looking for a technique that might find a nice expression for  $F_n^2-F_m^2$ in the instance where $n-m$ is odd. I should ask this as a new question though.

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align}
F_{n+2}^2 &= (F_n+F_{n+1})^2 = F_n^2 + F_{n+1}^2 + 2F_nF_{n+1} = 2F_n F_{n+1} + (F_n+F_{n-1})^2 + F_n^2\\
& = 2F_nF_{n+1} + 2F_n^2 + 2F_n F_{n-1} + F_{n-1}^2 = 2F_nF_{n+1} + 2F_n(F_n+F_{n-1}) + F_{n-1}^2\\
F_{n+2}^2 - F_{n-1}^2 & = 4F_nF_{n+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. What I am wondering is: can it be done in one line with a suitable identity?

Comment: I've adjusted the question to reflect this desire!